# Javascript: the confuse about comparison "2 == true"

Tags: javascript, comparison

Here is a javascript comparison:

```
2 == true //false
```

it's said, the reason why return false, is because the comparison convert the `true` to `Number` datatype, and result is 1:

```
console.info(Number(true)) // 1
```

My confuse is, why the comparison don't convert the number `2` to `Boolean` datatype

```
console.info(Boolean(2)) // true
```

and the `2 == true` result could be `true` ?

Comment: It's all about type-casting and falsy and truthy values. It's not converting the value to a boolean... Look that up, then you'll understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the doc here:

[Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), which said:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number
>   or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else
>   if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a
>   string if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript
>   compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to
>   the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

== does implicit conversion to compare. In this case `2` is number and `true` is boolean. The conversion rule is "while comparing a number to boolean, boolean will be converted to number" hence

> true is converted to 1

and 2 == 1 will be false.

```
//similarly, 
2 == false; //false
```

As false will be converted to 0 and 2 cannot be equal to 0 either.

However, 1 == true. for the same reason as true would be converted to 1 and 1==1